# Can Bitwise complement of a hex color code always return 6 characters?

Tags: javascript, hex, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

In Javascript, is there a way to make the bitwise complement of a hex color always return a 6 character string?

For instance, `('0xff0537' ^ '0xffffff').toString(16)` generates a 4 character string of `'fac8'`.

However, a `('0x00adeb' ^ '0xffffff').toString(16)` returns a 6 character string of `'ff5214'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue as so:

```
return ('000000' + (('0xffffff' ^ '0x00adeb').toString(16))).slice(-6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it into always 7 characters by adding a leading 1, convert to string and finally remove the first character to make it 6 again. That will keep the leading zeroes;

```
> (1<<24 | '0xff0537' ^ '0xffffff').toString(16).substring(1)
'00fac8'
```